# Restore an instance from snapshot without recreating using terraform

Tags: terraform

Use case: Intent is to revert an instance with already taken AWS snapshot of the volume the instance is currently running on.

For this, i thought why not use "terraform import" to bring the existing state of the instance and then modify HCL config file to replace ONLY volume. By behaviour it expect to create AMI from snapshot and then spawn instance from AMI. It works but it destroy's instance and then recreate instance.

I don't expect instance recreation, rather why not just do below by using terraform:

- stop instance
- detach current volume
- create volume from provided snapshot to revert to
- attach created volume to instance
- power on instance.

How to achieve above?

Current config file which i am trying after importing an instance:

```
provider "aws" {
…..
…..
…..
}

resource "aws_ami" "example5554" {
    name = "example5554"
    virtualization_type = "hvm"
    root_device_name = "/dev/sda1"

    ebs_block_device {
        snapshot_id = "snap-xxxxxxxxxxxxx”
        device_name = "/dev/sda1"
        volume_type = "gp2"
    }
}

resource "aws_instance" "arstest1new" {
    ami = "${aws_ami.example5554.id}"
    instance_type = "m4.large"
}
```